# How to replace element in array

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this map:

`{4: 5, 3: 5, 2: 6, 5: 2, 6: 1, 0: 1, 8: 1, 1: 1}`

where the first key is a **code** from this list

```
static final List<SensationItem> sensationList = [
    SensationItem(
        code: 0,
        title: 'Formicolio / Intorpidimento'),
    SensationItem(
        code: 1,
        title: 'Sudorazione intensa'),
    SensationItem(
        code: 2, title: 'Dolore al petto'),
    SensationItem(code: 3, title: 'Nausea'),
    SensationItem(code: 4, title: 'Tremori'),
    SensationItem(
        code: 5,
        title: 'Paura di perdere il controllo',
    SensationItem(
        code: 6,
        title: 'Sbandamento / Vertigini'),
    SensationItem(
        code: 7, title: 'Palpitazioni'),
    SensationItem(
        code: 8,
        title: 'Sensazione di soffocamento'),
  ];
}
```

I want to replace first key with code from **sensationList**

like something below

```
var result = ['Formicolio / Intorpidimento',1];
var result2 = ['Sudorazione intensa',8];
var result3 = ['Nausea',5];
var result4 = ['Palpitazioni',15];
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: This needs clarification. Do you want to generate variables? How Palpitazioni got paired with 15?

Comment: Yes! I need to add a series of variables in a bar chart. The first key in {4: 5, 3: 5, 2: 6, 5: 2, 6: 1, 0: 1, 8: 1, 1: 1} is code contained in "palpitazioni".

{code, quantity}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you a `List<List<Object>>`:

```
final result = myMap.entries
    .map((entry) => [
          sensationList
              .firstWhere((element) => element.code == entry.key)
              .title,
          entry.value
        ])
    .toList();
print(result);
// ([Tremori, 5], [Nausea, 5], [Dolore al petto, 6], ..., [Sensazione di soffocamento, 1], [Sudorazione intensa, 1])
```